# Don't allow to quote below the sales price of a product in openerp

Tags: python, xml, openerp-7

While we make quotations to customers, don't allow users to quote below the sales price of products. How can we achieve this? Please help me. Am using v7.. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call the function for the field `price_unit` in the view xml

```
<xpath expr="//field[@name='price_unit']" position="attributes">
   <attribute name="on_change">check_margin(product_id,price_unit)</attribute>
</xpath>
```

and in the class, define the function to process it.

```
def check_margin(self, cr, uid, ids, product_id, unit_price, context=None):
  res = {}
  warning = {}
  sale_price = None
  if product_id:
     sale_price = self.pool.get('product.product').browse(cr, uid,product_id).list_price
  if unit_price is None:
     pass
  elif unit_price < sale_price:
     warning = {  
       'title': _("Warning"),  
       'message': _('Unit price given, is less than the sales price of the selected product. Please change (or contact your sales manager to change) the sales price of the selected product.'),  
               }
     res = {'value': {'price_unit':sale_price}}
  elif unit_price >= sale_price:
     res = {'value': {'price_unit':unit_price}}
     pass
  return {'value': res.get('value'), 'warning':warning}
```

Comment: Thank you for posting the solution to your problem. We need more of this. However, can you provide some details of the file where you found the class and the name of the view you used?

Comment: Happy to help you.. Firstly we will go to About Openerp -> activate developer mode. then go to quotation form under sales. there you can see what  are the database fields,tables, etc and the name of the xml view files from it

Comment: edit form view->external id gives the view id and view fields will gives the database fields and table details..

Comment: I suggest that ,  don't  edit on source code , create a separate module for this thing.